# Getting Error 405 (Not Allowed) on PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, http-status-code-405

I'm trying to use PHPMailer to send emails from a contact form. Once submitted, the server doesn't respond for more than 5 minutes, then results in `ERROR 405 Not Allowed - ngnix`.

I'm using SMTP Auth from webmaster@mydomain.com, and the SMTP server is located at voyager.websitewelcome.com. I thought, "Could it be because of the cross-domain submission, even though this isn't AJAX and is all PHP?"

Nope, see answer below:

```
mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'voyager.websitewelcome.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'webmaster@mydomain.com';
$mail->Password = 'mypassword';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; //<---- THIS is the problem
$mail->Port = 465;

$mail->setFrom('webmaster@mydomain', 'My Company Kiosk');
$mail->addAddress('me@mydomain.com', 'My Name');

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = 'New Lead from My Company';
$mail->Body    = '<b>test</b> html'; //$body;
$mail->AltBody = 'test text';


try {
  $mail->send();
  //echo $output;
}
catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not that the server doesn't allow TLS, it's that you're trying to use explicit SSL (`SMTP+STARTTLS` == `'tls'` in PHPMailer) on a port expecting implicit SSL (`SMTPS`). You could also have fixed it (in a way not deprecated since 1998) by setting `$mail->Port = 587;`, which is what [the documentation](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) suggests (look under "using encryption").

Incidentally your error trapping will not work because PHPMailer does not throw exceptions by default, you need to pass `true` to the constructor to enable them, like this:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer! This is much more informative than my accidental discovery. My SMTP server setup suggestion claims to accept both TLS and SSL on that port, so I didn't think to try port 587. I'll give that a try since TLS is more secure and this involves customers' personal information. If that doesn't work, I'll give them a call and see if the guy knows anything about the port configuration. And thanks for the update about error trapping, I completely missed that.

Answer (score 0):

In the middle of writing this question, "TLS" caught my eye. I never thought to change this, and my SMTP server does not allow TLS!

I've read through so many posts trying to figure this out. I thought someone ought to post a possible answer!

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
```